# mod_cband or similar module for lighttpd to setup bandwidth limit on Geo-different users

Tags: apache, video-streaming, lighttpd, pseudo-streaming

I have been using mod_cband to limit bandwidth for different users from different countries, such as using CBandClassRemoteSpeed and CBandClassLimit parameters.

The webserver is for pseudo  mp4 streaming. I am thinking to use Lighttpd instead as it provides better performance for static contents. Is there anything equivalent method in Lighttpd that can limit bandwidth for Geo-Different users?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

An "organic" approach using lighttpd's own capabilities:

```
$HTTP["remoteip"] == "1.0.0.0/29" {
connection.kbytes-per-second = 2500
}
```

...for every larger block specific to an area. (Example covers a large chunk of North America). Get them all here: https://db-ip.com/db/download/country